# How to create ERC20 token with burns 0.5% of tokens on transfer?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, transactions, tokens

I want to create an ERC20 token. It must burn 0.5% of the tokens at every transfer. For example, When someone send 100 tokens from wallet1 to wallet2, wallet 2 must take 99.5 tokens.

Answer (score 2):

The [BOMB token](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1C95b093d6C236d3EF7c796fE33f9CC6b8606714#code) does something like this. Their `transfer` function is as follows:

```
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    require(value <= _balances[msg.sender]);
    require(to != address(0));

    uint256 tokensToBurn = findOnePercent(value);
    uint256 tokensToTransfer = value.sub(tokensToBurn);

    _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].sub(value);
    _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(tokensToTransfer);

    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(tokensToBurn);

    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokensToTransfer);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), tokensToBurn);
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for answer I was looking for it!